# Many toggle-slide elements in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script multiple times to hide some text:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button_to_click_to_toggle").click(function(){
    $("#hidden_div").slideToggle("medium");
  });
});
```

I want to make it impossible to toggle two hidden divs at once.

**Example:**

Click on one button (#button1) = the hidden div (#div1) associated to that button shows.

Click another button (#button2) = The div (#div2) associated to that button shows and at the same time #div1 closes (slide to close).

Click another button (#button3) = The div (#div3) associated to that button shows and at the same time #div2 closes (slide to close).

Comment: What about using a jQuery UI accordion? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class `.button` to all of the buttons and `.div` to all divs.  Then it's just a matter of:

```
$(".button").on('click', function () {
  var id = this.id.replace('button', '');

  //properly toggle visibility of selected div
  if ($("#div" + id).is(":visible")) {
     $("#div" + id).slideUp();
  }
  else {
    $("#div" + id).slideDown();
  }
   //hide all divs except the selected one
   $(".div").not("#div" + id).slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lhxm/

Comment: @Wobot make sure that you are correctly using the classes "button" and "div" as in my example -- your HTML needs to be compatible.  You can create a jsfiddle with your relevant HTML / the JS code you are using, and I will try to help you out.

Comment: @Wobot seems to be working for me; is there a particular browser it's not working in?

Comment: @Wobot I just tested out the fiddle in Chrome/IE8+9 and it worked.  It could be a caching issue.  Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22493/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-wobot)

Answer (score 0):

Could also hide all the divs on click and then show only the associated one:

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("div").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
  });
});
```

html:

```
<button type="button">one</button>
<div id="one">one</div>
<button type="button">two</button>
<div id="two">two</div>
<button type="button">three</button>
<div id="three">three</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7Ehq/

Comment: I manage also to do something like this code but problem when adding the slide function.

Comment: I know you've got a working answer now, but to use the above, you can make the slideDown a callback of the slideUp function: http://jsfiddle.net/x7Ehq/2/